# how to set button and rect for particular columns in table using d3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, nvd3.js

I have following code.. I just want to add button in one column and rect in one column of table.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "a",
  "section": 1,
  "stars": "d1"
}, {
  "name": "b",
  "section": 2,
  "stars": "d2"
}, {
  "name": "c",
  "section": 1,
  "stars": "d3"
}];

var columns = ['name', 'section', 'stars']
  // create table
var table = d3.select("#table").append("table");

var thead = table.append("thead").append("tr");

thead.selectAll("th")
  .data(columns)
  .enter()
  .append("th")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var tbody = table.append("tbody");
thead.append("th").text('Action');
data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  trow = tbody.append("tr")
  trow.selectAll("td")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .text(function(e) {
      return d[e]
    });
  trow.selectAll("td.button")
    //use a class so you don't re-select the existing <td> elements
    .data(function(d) {
      return [d];
    })
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .attr("class", "button")
    .append("button")
    .text(function(d) {
      return "ADD"
    })
    .on("click", function(d) {
      console.log(d);
      alert("particular row data" + JSON.stringify(d))
    });
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

how to add button in section column and how to insert rect in stars column.

Comment: You're code doesn't run so I don't know why you put it as an executable

Comment: s i have to fix that

Comment: now its working right?

Comment: thank you for editing @gilsha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hope you are looking for a similar output in following code snippet.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "a",
  "section": 1,
  "stars": "d1"
}, {
  "name": "b",
  "section": 2,
  "stars": "d2"
}, {
  "name": "c",
  "section": 1,
  "stars": "d3"
}];

var columns = ['name', 'section', 'stars']
  // create table
var table = d3.select("#table").append("table");

var thead = table.append("thead").append("tr");

thead.selectAll("th")
  .data(columns)
  .enter()
  .append("th")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });

var tbody = table.append("tbody");
thead.append("th").text('Action');

data.forEach(function(d, i) {
  trow = tbody.append("tr");  
  trow.append("td")
    .text(d["name"]);
  
  trow.append("td")
    .attr("class", "button")
    .append("button")
    .text("ADD")
    .on("click", function() {     
      alert("particular row data" + JSON.stringify(d))
    });
  
  var svg = trow.append("td")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width",30)
    .attr("height",20);
  
  svg.append("rect")
    .attr("x",0)
    .attr("y",0)
    .attr("width",30)
    .attr("height",20)
    .style("stroke","red")
    .style("fill","black");
  
  svg.append("text")
  .attr("x",15)
  .attr("dy",10)
  .text(d["stars"])
  .attr("text-anchor","middle")
  .style("stroke","white")
  .style("alignment-baseline","central");
});
```

```css
div {
  height: 250px;
  width: 500px;;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="table"></div>
```

Comment: ya its working fine..i have to insert the text inside the rect in stars column

Comment: the text should be the star column data

Answer (score 2):

What Gilsha said is right but here is another way of doing the same.

You can do it this way as well using a condition in the `append` function like below.

```
trow.selectAll("td")
    .data(columns)
    .enter()
    .append("td")
    .append(function(d) {
      if (d == "stars") {
        return document.createElement('button');
      } else
        return document.createElement('div');
    })
    .attr("class", function(d) {
      if (d == "section") {
        return "rect"//rect using style.
      }
    })
    .text(function(e) {
      return d[e]
    });
```

for rectangle I used style.

```
.rect {
  outline: 1px solid green;
}
```

working code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyril123/cma34scx/)